Springboot can't locate my com.example.domain.User.java
I'm starting my first springboot project and all was okay untill I found this issue:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'controllerREST': Unsatisfied dependency
expressed through field 'userDao': Error creating bean with name
'IUserDao' defined in com.example.dao.IUserDao defined in
@EnableJpaRepositories declared on WeatherStartingAppApplication: Not
a managed type: class com.example.domain.User

I believe there's something wrong with my folders structure:
packages
This is the main class:
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.dao")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.domain")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")

@SpringBootApplication
public class WeatherStartingAppApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WeatherStartingAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}


ControllerREST:
package com.example.controller;

import com.example.domain.User;
import com.example.dao.IUserDao;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
@Slf4j
public class ControllerREST {

    @Autowired
    private IUserDao userDao;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model){   
        Iterable<User> users = userDao.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "index";
    }
}

IUserDao:
package com.example.dao;

import com.example.domain.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository

public interface IUserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}


User:
package com.example.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private int dni;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String mail;

    public User() {
        // Default constructor required by JPA
    }

    public User(int dni, String name, String surname, String mail) {
        this.dni = dni;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + dni + ' ' + name + ' ' + surname + ' ' + mail + "}";
    }
}

The pom file is okay, all dependencies needed are there, I've installed all requirements.

Try removing @EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.domain") and @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example"). Also remove the basePackages from the @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.dao") let like this: @EnableJpaRepositories

Which version of Spring Boot are you using? If it's 3 you should be importing jakarta.persistence instead of javax.persistence

Oh it was it, thank you so much, I didn't know I should use jakarta with the latest spring boot version. I'm new with this

Give a try to this template I made so long ago... https://github.com/efsandino/sbfj18
